# UDP Multicast: Socket.SendTo is blocking

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp, multicast

I've an application that send multicast packets.

I use a BlockingCollection to store message that I've to send and then a thread is dedicated to send just iterate over this collection and send message in it. I've a socket for each local IP, since I need to send it on each IP.

It usually works nice, but recently, I had several times my thread hanging on the Socket.SendTo call, causing my application to not respond anymore to any external call. My BlockingCollection get bigger and bigger and is never treated.

I can't find any reason to have this Socket.SendTo call that is blocking my call. If it was a TCP call, I can imagine that there is nobody on the other side, but here with UDP, I don't see any possible issue.

My code is basically:

```
Debug.WriteLine("Sending message on local endpoint " + socket.Key + ", to " + remoteEndpoint);
int sendTo = socket.Value.SendTo(buffer, remoteEndpoint);
Debug.WriteLine("Successfully sent a packet with "+sendTo+" bytes");
```

In my logs I see:

```
[...]
Sending message on local endpoint 10.10.23.56, to 224.0.0.253:5353
Successfully sent a packet with 778 bytes
Sending message on local endpoint 10.9.53.38, to 224.0.0.253:5353
Successfully sent a packet with 778 bytes
Sending message on local endpoint 127.0.0.1, to 224.0.0.253:5353
Successfully sent a packet with 778 bytes
Sending message on local endpoint 10.10.23.56, to 224.0.0.253:5353
Successfully sent a packet with 778 bytes
Sending message on local endpoint 10.9.53.38, to 224.0.0.253:5353
Successfully sent a packet with 778 bytes
Sending message on local endpoint 127.0.0.1, to 224.0.0.253:5353
Successfully sent a packet with 778 bytes
Sending message on local endpoint 10.10.23.56, to 224.0.0.253:5353
Successfully sent a packet with 778 bytes
Sending message on local endpoint 10.9.53.38, to 224.0.0.253:5353¨
```

I create my socket like this:

```
Socket sendSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
sendSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 255);
sendSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
sendSocket.MulticastLoopback = true;
sendSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(localAddress, m_port));
sendSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership,new MulticastOption(m_multicastAddress, localAddress));
```

I saw [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eae4f5y0.aspx) that it's blocking until all my message is sent, but for what reason my message may be blocked like this? But here, it makes minutes that my call is blocked here.

And what to do? Have a time that dispose the Socket and try to create it again when my packet is not sent?

EDIT: I tried to do the same thing with async send/receive, but it's even worse: I still get blocked on EndReceiveTo, but additionally, it prevent me to kill the process(Access denied and I'm Admin, had to reboot :/)

**EDIT**
After the xaxxon answer, I put this  before sending my messages, to see if I've socket on which I can't write or are in error:

```
List<Socket> socketWrite = socketToUse.Select(s => s.Value).ToList();
List<Socket> socketError = socketToUse.Select(s => s.Value).ToList();
Socket.Select(null, socketWrite, socketError, 1000);
Console.WriteLine("Writeable sockets: " + String.Join(", ", socketWrite.Select(s => s.LocalEndPoint.ToString())));
Console.WriteLine("Sockets in errors: " + String.Join(", ", socketError.Select(s => s.LocalEndPoint.ToString())));

But before I enter I get stuck  on my `SendTo` call, 
Writeable sockets: 10.10.23.56:5353, 10.9.53.38:5353, 127.0.0.1:5353
Sockets in errors:
Sending message on local endpoint 10.10.23.56, to 224.0.0.253:5353
Successfully sent a packet with 93 bytes
Sending message on local endpoint 10.9.53.38, to 224.0.0.253:5353
Successfully sent a packet with 93 bytes
Sending message on local endpoint 127.0.0.1, to 224.0.0.253:5353
Successfully sent a packet with 93 bytes
Writeable sockets: 10.10.23.56:5353, 10.9.53.38:5353, 127.0.0.1:5353
Sockets in errors:
Sending message on local endpoint 10.10.23.56, to 224.0.0.253:5353
Successfully sent a packet with 1162 bytes
Sending message on local endpoint 10.9.53.38, to 224.0.0.253:5353
__HERE I GET STUCK
```

Comment: You're doing loopback but you aren't reading it. If you're not going to read it, don't set loopback.

Comment: But, it's UDP multicast, it should not be necessary to read them. In addition I already them(twice in fact, the server listen message, and the client too). But this is not my current issue, since I was blocking on another IP

Comment: If you don't want to read them why are you enabling loopback? It doesn't make sense. Note that these are comments not answers.

Comment: Because sometimes I need to have them(like when having client and server on the same workstation). But again, it's not my current issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mess around with socket send buffers.  There is no possible way to ever get this right for all situations.

Instead, use nonblocking sockets, and check to see if the socket is writeable before sending. This will let you fill up the buffer when there is space available.

Comment: Thank you. How can I check if a socket si writeable? What would be the correct behavior if I see that it's not writable? I mean, I need to send the message, so it would have the same effect to wait that the buffer is writable than wait on the buffer no? Non-blocking socket = async socket? Since the only job of this thread is to send packet, if I do it the async way, it will try directly to send the next one, I'm not sure it's the good solution?

Comment: I'm not a c# guy, but `select` is the function in most lanaguages you're looking for.

Comment: Select? I don't see any way to do this call on my socket object :/

Comment: Sorry, I was checking in Members. But what would be a good behavior when detecting that a socket buffer is full? Because I need to have all messages sent?

Comment: I added an "Edit" of my post to show you the result, I'm not sure why I'm getting blocked then?

Comment: In fact, if I use `socket.Poll()`, I can detect that I cannot send message. But it's weird, I get blocked several minutes, when the buffer get empty, it should be empty very fast no?

Answer (score 2):

Like TCP sockets, even UDP sockets have an outgoing (send) buffer. If that send buffer is full, then even sendTo() call will block. You can try to set the SO_SNDBUF socket option to increase the size of the outgoing send buffer.  Yet another reason is if you need to resolve ARP. This can happen, if either the next hop in the route or the destination itself is in the same subnet and there is no ARP entry. Since ARP resolution consists of ARP request/ARP response, it is possible that by the time you receive the ARP response, the sender has already enqueued enough packets to fill the send buffer. I would try to increase the SO_SNDBUF progressively and see if the problem you are running into becomes less severe -- this would help identify that the send buffer is indeed the cause of the blocking issue.

Here is a link that talks about setting SO_SNDBUF.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I will test it ASAP. This buffer is based on the number of packet ? the size? Do we have an idea of what is needed to fill this outgoing buffer? Because I don't have the impression that I fill it very fastly. I've two application(client and server), for tests, I run both on the same computer(With REUSE_ADDRESS). I think that it's a common buffer for both client and server then? But the other client has no issues.

Comment: @J4N the buffer is based on number of bytes and not packets. When we have two sockets, both sockets gets their own send buffer, even if they are bound to the same port (using reuse address option).

Comment: It's really bad advice to mess with buffer sizes.  You'll never be able to predict how much data you will have to send or what the OS will allow you to do.  Nonblocking I/O is the only way to go.

Comment: In general, I agree with your comment. But, as long as you know what you are doing, it should be okay to tweak sockets based on these options -- after all, that is why socket layer provides these options. I assumed that the application does not want to go the nonblocking way since with that the application would have to figure out when to retry once it gets EWOULDBLOCK/EAGAIN error.

Comment: The problem is that I can never be sure it will always works. I think I will use this solution to increase non-blocking send message, but I still need a way to detect and resolve this issue.

Comment: In fact I found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname.aspx the description of the SendBuffer, but it says it's only for TCP connection. Does this work for UDP too?

Comment: @J4N, the note says that, "Specifies the total per-socket buffer space reserved for sends. This is unrelated to the maximum message size or the size of a TCP window." Basically, it is saying that this option is not related to TCP MSS or TCP window size. But, it does not say that it is not only applicable to TCP. You can always use Socket.GetSocketOption() to see the current value of UDP send buffer and upon setting it to a new value, you can verify that hte value is different. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.getsocketoption.aspx

Comment: Is there any way to know how much data is actually in the output buffer of a non blocking UDP socket on Windows ?